# Strange error session get destroyed

Tags: session, yii2

I have a problem when I execute controller method it process controller code but destroy all session including user.

So after process thus controller and I try to open home page, there is no logged in account.

I'm sure no destroy session code, nor logout code in my controller. and I can say this is not about session expired.

I don't know what wrong is this about code, yii2 configuration or logic, but is someone have similar problem in past?

Hope you can guide me to solve this problem.

If you need more information, please let me know.

This not related to code maybe, but here is my controller code.

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\TbCustomer;
use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\Model;
use common\models\VwProdukAgent;
use common\models\TbCart;
use yii\helpers\VarDumper;
use common\models\VwProduk;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\VwProdukCustomer;
use common\models\TbCustomerShipment;
use common\component\BeoHelper;
use common\models\TbProdukEkspedisi;
use common\models\TbKota;
use yii\helpers\Url;


/**
 * CustomerController implements the CRUD actions for TbCustomer model.
 */
class Pengiriman1Controller extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        Yii::$app->timeZone = 'Asia/Jakarta';
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {
            //$url = Url::to([['home'],'message'=>'Anda Harus Login Terlebih Dahulu']);
            \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('message', \Yii::t('app', 'Anda Harus Login Terlebih Dahulu'));
            $this->goHome();
            return FALSE;
        }

        //if ($action->id == 'my-method') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        //  }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        //get alamat customer
        //$lsalamat = array();
        if(!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
        {


            BeoHelper::refreshCart();

            //cek cart kosong atau tidak
            if(isset(\Yii::$app->session['produkcart']))
            {
                $lsproduk = \Yii::$app->session['produkcart'];
                if (count($lsproduk)<1)
                {
                    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('message',"silahkan berbelanja terlebih dahulu");
                    return $this->redirect(Url::to(['cart/index']));
                }
            }

            $customer_id = Yii::$app->user->id; 
            $message = '';
            $model = null;
            if(\Yii::$app->request->post('opsi_alamat',null)!=null)
            {
                $opsi_pengiriman = \Yii::$app->request->post('opsi_alamat',null);
                //return $opsi_pengiriman;
                if($opsi_pengiriman == 'new')
                {
                    $model = new TbCustomerShipment();
                    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
                    $model->customer_id = $customer_id;
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        \Yii::$app->session['shipemenadd'] = $model;
                        //get kurir preselected
                        if(isset(\Yii::$app->session['produkcart']))
                        {
                            $hargatotal = 0;
                            $lsproduk = \Yii::$app->session['produkcart'];
                            $i=0;
                            $lsprodukedit = array();
                            foreach ($lsproduk as $produk)
                            {
                                //pre selected
                                $pengiriman = TbProdukEkspedisi::find()->where(['produk_id' => $produk->produk_id])->one();
                                $kode = $pengiriman->idEkspedisi->kode_ekspedisi;
                                $service = $pengiriman->idEkspedisi->service;
                                $produk->kurir = $kode;
                                $kota_asal = TbKota::find()->where("kota_id = $produk->kota_id ")->one();
                                $kota_tujuan = TbKota::find()->where("kota_id = $model->kota_id ")->one();

                                $berat_produk = $produk->kuantitas *$produk->berat_produk;
                                $berat_produk = round($berat_produk);
                                $result = BeoHelper::getCostEkspedisi($kota_asal->api_id, $kota_tujuan->api_id, $berat_produk, $kode,$service,$produk->produk_id);
                                if(count($result)!=0)
                                {

                                    $produk->harga_kurir = $result[0]['value'];
                                    $produk->estimasi_sampai = $result[0]['etd'];
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    $message = "pilihan kurir untuk lokasi tersebut tidak tersedia";
                                }
                                //return VarDumper::dump($result);

                                $lsprodukedit[$i++] = $produk;
                                $hargatotal += $produk->kuantitas * $produk->harga_agen;


                            }
                            \Yii::$app->session['produkcart'] = $lsprodukedit;
                        }   
                        if(isset(Yii::$app->session['shipemenadd'])){
                            return "exists";        
                        }else{
                            return "doesn't exist";
                        }
                        //return $this->redirect(['pengiriman2/index','message'=>$message]);
                        //print_r(Yii::$app->session['shipemenadd']);
                    }
                    //else 
                    //{
                    //  VarDumper::dump($model);
                    //}
                }
                else 
                {
                    $pengiriman_selected = TbCustomerShipment::find()->where("customer_shipment_id = $opsi_pengiriman")->one();
                    \Yii::$app->session['shipemenadd'] = $pengiriman_selected;

                    if(isset(\Yii::$app->session['produkcart']))
                    {
                        $hargatotal = 0;
                        $lsproduk = \Yii::$app->session['produkcart'];
                        $i=0;
                        $lsprodukedit = array();
                        foreach ($lsproduk as $produk)
                        {
                            //pre selected
                            $pengiriman = TbProdukEkspedisi::find()->where("produk_id =$produk->produk_id")->one();
                            $kode = $pengiriman->idEkspedisi->kode_ekspedisi;
                            $service = $pengiriman->idEkspedisi->service;
                            $produk->kurir = $kode;
                            //get kota id rajaongkir
                            $kota_asal = TbKota::find()->where("kota_id = $produk->kota_id ")->one();
                            $kota_tujuan = TbKota::find()->where("kota_id = $pengiriman_selected->kota_id ")->one();

                            //$result = BeoHelper::getCostEkspedisi($kota_asal->api_id, $kota_tujuan->api_id, $produk->berat_produk, $kode,$service);
                            //return VarDumper::dump($result);
                            //if(count($result)!=0)
                            //{

                                //$produk->harga_kurir = $result[0]['value'];
                                //$produk->estimasi_sampai = $result[0]['etd'];
                                $produk->harga_kurir = 0;
                                $produk->estimasi_sampai = 0;
                            //}
                            //else 
                            //{
                            //  $message = "pilihan kuriri untuk lokasi tersebut tidak tersedia";
                            //}
                            $lsprodukedit[$i++] = $produk;
                            $hargatotal += $produk->kuantitas * $produk->harga_agen;
                        }
                        \Yii::$app->session['produkcart'] = $lsprodukedit;
                    }

                    return $this->redirect(['pengiriman2/index','message'=>$message]);
                }
            }

            $lsalamat = TbCustomerShipment::find()->where(['customer_id'=>$customer_id])->all();
            if(count($lsalamat)==0)
            //insert to tb shipment
            {
                $datacustomer = TbCustomer::find()->where(['customer_id'=>$customer_id])->one();
                $newalamat = new TbCustomerShipment();
                $newalamat->customer_id = $customer_id;
                $newalamat->kota_id = $datacustomer->kota_id;
                $newalamat->kecamatan_id = $datacustomer->kecamatan_id;
                $newalamat->negara_id = $datacustomer->negara_id;
                $newalamat->propinsi_id = $datacustomer->propinsi_id;
                $newalamat->alamat = $datacustomer->alamat;
                $newalamat->shipment_name = "Alamat Rumah";
                $newalamat->penerima = $datacustomer->nama;
                $newalamat->hp_penerima = $datacustomer->hp;
                $newalamat->save();
            }
            $lsalamat = TbCustomerShipment::find()->where(['customer_id'=>$customer_id])->all();
            return $this->render('index',['lsalamat'=>$lsalamat,'newalamat'=> $model]);
        }
        else 
        {
            return $this->goHome();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: try replacing `\Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('message', \Yii::t('app', 'Anda Harus Login Terlebih Dahulu'))` with `\Yii::$app->session->setFlash('message', 'Anda Harus Login Terlebih Dahulu)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the problem

```
\Yii::$app->session['shipemenadd'] = $model;
```

it should

```
$currentTbCustomerShipment = TbCustomerShipment::find()->where(['customer_user_id' => $model->customer_user_id])->one(); //find latest object
Yii::$app->session['shipemenadd'] = $currentTbCustomerShipment;
```